# android httpurlconnection slow on data connection

Tags: android, http, httpurlconnection, keep-alive

Why is the first http request on data so slow?

I'm using something on the following lines: Doing 3 HTTP requests in a row (one after each other) and then wait a given time and loop again with doing the 3 HTTP requests.

I'm using keep-alive which is basically also working but on the first HTTP request there is a 2 second penalty each time I start with the 3 HTTP request. Only the first HTTP request has this 2 second penalty. If I lower the time waiting between the consecutive HTTP requests to something like 200ms all of the request are fast without having the first one seeing this 2 second penalty.

Obviously this sounds like the first request might not use the keep alive connection but that is actually not the case. I run tcpdump on the server and I can clearly see that all requests are using the same TCP connection without closing and building up again a new connection. The keep alive setting on the server is set to 60s while the time waiting on the app is for example 5 seconds. Also when I switch to WIFI this behavior I cannot see. With the same time waiting all requests are fast.

The http connect code is using HttpURLConnection and looks like the following:

```
m_res.error = null;
HttpURLConnection connection;
try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection)(new URL(m_url + "/" + m_call.command).openConnection());
    connection.setDoOutput(true); // triggers POST.
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", m_charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=" + m_charset);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
    //connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
    OutputStream output = null;

    try {
        output = connection.getOutputStream();
        output.write(m_call.query_string.getBytes(m_charset));
        InputStream response = null;
        try {
            response = connection.getInputStream();
            if ("gzip".equals(connection.getContentEncoding())) {
                response = new GZIPInputStream(response);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            response = connection.getErrorStream();
        }
        if (response == null) {
            m_res.error = "Connection Error";
        }
        else {
            m_res.body = getAsString(response);
            m_res.status = connection.getResponseCode();
        }
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        m_res.error = "Connection Error";
    }
    finally {
        if (output != null) 
                try { 
                    output.close(); 
                } catch (IOException logOrIgnore) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and your question is ...

Comment: Why is the first http request on data connection so slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one possible answer to this is that the devices data connection on a layer below IP is changing its status e.g. maybe there is some sort of standby status which kicks in when there is no incoming or outgoing data for a given time e.g. like in my example 5 seconds.

Comment: This is indeed how phones work : when idle, the power down to a standby state that takes a little longer to connect. If it stays idle even longer then they power down the radio to idle and that takes even longer.

Comment: Is this somewhere documented?

Comment: Here you go : http://blog.radioactiveyak.com/2012/03/understanding-mobile-radio-state-to.html

Comment: Also, take a look at some of the information here too about how the state machine for networks works https://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=8100027

Answer (score 0):

Check out the ARO tool that allows you to see what is happening at a network level. https://developer.att.com/developer/aro
The analyzer will show you all the different network communications that are happening and help you to make more efficient use of the network.
The other link I posted in my comment explains the state machine and what happens with connections at different times when idle.

Answer (score 0):

you can use volley library and it's feature..
1. Request queuing and prioritization
2. Effective request cache and memory management
3. Extensibility and customization of the library to our needs
4. Cancelling the requests

and use this link http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/